# How do i check if DHCP is enabled?

Tags: networking, dhcp, ipv4

I have a VM running Debian 9 and the latest version of VirtualBox. I have VirtualBox configured to use the bridged adapter and it was working fine yesterday. But when I came and got on it this morning... I am unable to access the network from it or the internet. Here is the output of `ip address show`

[image: ip address show output]

Comment: Just `systemctl restart networking.service`, and to verify if your dhclient is still running: `ps -elf | grep dhclient`

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a new IP address through DHCP, dhclient must be running. You can run it manually to confirm it works.

Then check your /etc/network/interfaces file, it should contain a line like:

```
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

if it doesn't, add it and restart the network with

```
systemctl restart networking
```